# How to create a list where each entry is another list containing information from csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, sorting

Hi all can anyone help me figuring out how to create a list where each entry is another list containing information from csv. Here is a sample of the csv file that I'm working with:

```
,aecousticnss,danceability,duration_ms,energy,instrumentalness,key,liveness,loudness,mode,speechiness,tempo,time_signature,valence,target,song_title,artist
0,0.0102,0.833,204600,0.434,0.0219,2,0.165,-8.795,1,0.431,150.062,4,0.286,1,Mask Off,Future
1,0.199,0.743,326933,0.359,0.00611,1,0.137,-10.401,1,0.0794,160.083,4,0.588,1,Redbone,Childish Gambino
2,0.0344,0.838,185707,0.412,0.000234,2,0.159,-7.148,1,0.289,75.044,4,0.173,1,Xanny Family,Future
```

So far I have done this:

```
storage = []

artists = open("spotify.csv")
artist= input("Who is your favourite 
artist?: ")
junk = artists.readline()
 for data in artists:
  datalist = data.strip("\n").split(",")
  if datalist[16] == artist: 
    storage = storage  + 
[datalist[15],datalist[3]]
print(storage)
```

Also, how can I sort the list using python 3 sort function?

Comment: Please dont poast screen shots of your input data, just copy a sample of it into the question

Comment: ok sorry Im new to this I will fix it

Comment: Your ask is very unclear. List containing lists? What is the list and what are those other lists? Please give an example.

Comment: ok so what I want to do is to make a list that contains all the song titles based on artist given by the user then add characteristics to like danceablity the list then sort it.

Comment: danceability? What is that?

Comment: it one of the section in the CSV file indicated on the first line of the file and shown as a integer. For example looking at the second line under ,aecousticnss,danceability,duration_ms, it show that 0,0.0102,0.833,204600, and dancablity is 0.0102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as an example of how to do this you can read the first line and use it as keys, then for each line you read use the keys and the line data to make a dict. That makes it easier in the code to understand what field we are talking about rather than just mentioning arbitrary index values.

once you have your list of artists you can sort it by any field in your list. Remember that all fields from the line will be a string so if we want to sort by number we need to convert them to ints.

```py
fav_artist = input("who is your fav artist: ")
fav_artist_songs = []
with open('test.dat') as artists:
    data = {}
    keys = artists.readline().rstrip().split(',')
    for line in artists:
        data = dict(zip(keys, line.rstrip().split(',')))
        if data['artist'] == fav_artist:
            fav_artist_songs.append([data['song_title'], data['duration_ms']])

duration_low_to_high = sorted(fav_artist_songs, key= lambda song: int(song[1]))
song_name_a_2_z = sorted(fav_artist_songs, key= lambda song: song[0])
print(duration_low_to_high)
print(song_name_a_2_z)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
who is your fav artist: Future
[['Xanny Family', '185707'], ['Mask Off', '204600']]
[['Mask Off', '204600'], ['Xanny Family', '185707']]
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation do you know where I can go to understand more about sorting I'm really confused.

Comment: sort can take a bit of time to get the hang of. In this case just remember that we give sorted our list, and it will then give each inner the list to lambda. So the lambda will receive the inner list and we can chose what to return. so in the case of song_name we return the first element of the inner list. So sort then has a list of all the song names from the inner lists and sorts the lists using that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list of lists simply by appending to the outer list.

```py
master_list = []
for n in range(5):
    master_list.append(range(n))
print(master_list)
# [[], [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
for sub_list in master_list:
    print(sub_list)
# []
# [0]
# [0, 1]
# [0, 1, 2]
# [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Using your code, try this:

```py
storage.append([datalist[15], datalist[3]])
```

You can sort a list in place using `my_list.sort()`, or you can store the sorted list in a new variable (leaving the original list unsorted) using `my_sorted_list = sorted(my_list)`.  Sequences (like lists) will be sorted first by their first value, and any ties will be broken by sorting by their second value, etc.  If you want to sort some other way, you can specify a key function which will be used to compare items. For example, if you wanted to sort a list of words by their second letter, you would do `word_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])` You can also sort in reverse order by using the reverse keyword, like this `my_list.sort(reverse=True)`.

Comment: Alright thank you sorry if my question is unclear I think you just solve it thank you again